# Where to include index.html <head/> class helper functions into ReactJS Component?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, reactjs

I have a class helper functions called `classie.js`:

```
( function( window ) {

'use strict';

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
```

And in the `index.html` `<head/>` do the following:

```
<script src="classie.js"></script>
<script>
  function init() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
          var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
              shrinkOn = 300,
              header = document.querySelector("header");
          if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
              classie.add(header,"smaller");
          } else {
              if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                  classie.remove(header,"smaller");
              }
          }
      });
  }
  window.onload = init();
</script>
```

In a Redux, Webpack, React Router, ReactJS project, where and how should these be included into a component?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the classie.js in your index.html where components will be rendered. You can then declare the functions (from classie.js) in your component as

```
declare function some_function(some_params);
```

Comment: I would like to get it to function just like how it is shown in the `index.html <head/>` that I provided? Also to clarify, by include the `classie.js` in my index.html, leave this `<script src="classie.js"></script>` declaration?